How to submit nested test suites with plugin qase-pytest?
I'm struggling to created nested suites when using qase-pytest plugin, hence in the docs, it can be use dot annotation to create the nested test suites but it doesn't works. I use the library from here https://github.com/qase-tms/qase-python/tree/main/qase-pytest
decorator function from qase-pytest :
@staticmethod
    def suite(title: str, description: str = None):
        """
        >>> @qase.suite("Sign up")
        >>> def test_example():
        >>>     pass

        :param title: a string with suite name. You can use dot notation to create nested suites.
        :param description: a string with suite description
        :return: pytest.mark instance
        """
        return pytest.mark.qase_suite(title=title, description=description)

how i used it :
from qase.pytest import qase


@qase.suite("First Suites.Second Suites.Third Suites")
@qase.title("This is Example Title")
def test_example():
    assert True


Instead of giving me this :
.
└── Root Suites/
    └── First Suites/
        └── Second Suites/
            └── Third Suites

its create a Suites like this First Suites.Second Suites.Third Suites

This is valid issue from qase-pytest plugin and it has been fixed in v.6.1.8.
Reference : https://github.com/qase-tms/qase-python/issues/296
